# pandoc skip latex environment

Tags: docx, pandoc, tex, tikz

I'm writing mainly in LaTeX, but some co-authors prefer MS Word. To facilitate their work a bit, I would like to convert the `.tex` file (or the `.pdf`) to a `.docx`. The formatting does not need to be perfect, but all of the text, equations, figures etc should be perfectly readable.

I'm currently thinking to take the `.tex` document, replace all the essential stuff and then let Pandoc do it's magic. For this I would preferably implement my additions as a Pandoc filter. E.g., my `tikz` pictures would be converted to `png` using the `tikz.py` filter provided with Pandoc. The problem I'm facing with this approach is that Pandoc tries to interpret the `tikz` environment upon conversion from `tex` into it's internal language and the filters take this internal language as an input. The result is that the `tikz` code is lost. Is there a way to tell Pandoc to leave any `tikzpicture` environments alone?

Edit:
See the MWE below:

MWE.tex contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0,0) -- (2,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output of `pandoc -t native MWE.tex`

```
[Para [Str "(0,0)",Space,Str "\8211",Space,Str "(2,2);"]]
```

The `\draw` command has completely disappeared as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

I found that pandoc does not skip code encapsulated in `\iffalse` ... `\fi`, so you can redefine the tikpicture environment as such (or in any other way you might like):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\iffalse
    \renewenvironment{tikzpicture}%
        {\par---start tikzpicture---\\}%
        {\\---end tikzpicture---\par}
    \renewcommand{\node}{node:}
\fi

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node {foo};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

With pandoc 2.5 this results in a docx file containing:

```
—start tikzpicture—
node:foo;
—end tikzpicture—
```

This feels very wrong, and I wish I knew a nicer way.

Comment: Upon asking this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63980367/check-if-latex-code-is-processed-by-pandoc-or-tex/63980840
I was kindly pointed to this issue: https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6096

A lot nicer would be to keep the redefinition of tikzpicture in a separate tex file and then call pandoc as `pandoc -i pandoc_redefinitions.tex paper.tex -o paper.docx`