# Pandoc: Remove equations because they are broken

Tags: pandoc

At the moment I am transforming a large .tex file into .docx. However, many of the equations are broken, also the figures. Since I need only the fulltext in the docx file: Is there a way to tell pandoc to neglect all the equation and figure environments and only to transform the text? This question is related to another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906254/pandoc-skip-latex-environment), which has not been answered yet.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document can be modified using [filters](https://pandoc.org/filters.html) or [Lua filters](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html). Below Lua filter would remove all equations and images:

```
-- file: remove-math-and-images.lua
function Math(_) return {} end
function Image(_) return {} end
```

Run with `pandoc --lua-filter remove-math-and-images.lua <other options>`. More sophisticated modifications are possible; e.g., this replaces all equations with a note hinting at the missing equation:

```
function Math(_)
  return pandoc.Str('<Equation removed>')
end
```