# Check if latex code is processed by Pandoc or *tex

Tags: latex, docx, pandoc

When converting a latex file to word, I'd like to skip some sections which Pandoc does not handle well, or redefine commands which pandoc does not understand. Now I use the following highly unelegant mechanism:

```
\iffalse
    % code executed by pandoc only
    \def\SI#1#2{#1\,\mathrm{#2}}
\fi
```

What is the correct way make pandoc execute (or skip) some sections of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is not available now. There is [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42906254/pandoc-skip-latex-environment) open and not answered yet. And I found also an [open issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/6096) for this behavior.

Comment: Thanks, That issue indeed seems to raise a similar issue. I've added my finings there.

Comment: Ah, so probably adding the code I want to be executed in another file and running that previous to the main file will solve it. I wasn't aware of that. At least I can hack something together that does not exploit missing functionality in pandoc